# How to make this CSS only Masonry horizontal?

Tags: html, css

How can I make this masonry CSS only layout organize from left to right? Currently the card stack order is top to bottom. I would like to maintain the same layout(every card has the same width), and just have them orgazine from left to right instead, like the red numbers on this picture:

[image]

The height of each card is not set, and they can vary depending on how many/few entries are in each of them.

```css
/* Defaults */

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #465665;
}

a {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d8dee9;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: #d8dee9;
}


/* The title */

.title {
  font-weight: 700;
}


/* Masonry grid */

.masonry {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  column-gap: 30px;
  column-fill: initial;
  max-width: 75vw;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
}

.brick {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Masonry item */

.masonry .brick {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Fix the misalignment of items */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* Keep the item on the very top */
}

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.3em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.card {
  background: #666;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 1.8vh;
  color: #d8dee9;
  padding-top: 4vh;
  padding-bottom: 4vh;
  padding-left: 3vh;
  padding-right: 3vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transform: translateY(-0.1rem);
}


/**
 * BOX HACKING
 */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* Masonry on tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .masonry {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}


/* Masonry on big screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .desc {
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
  .intro {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .masonry {
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="masonry">
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>1</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>2</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>3</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>4</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>5</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>6</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>7</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>8</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brick">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>9</h2>
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a class="bookmark" href="https://duckduckgo.com/">Text</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .masonry -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to include the relevant HTML here.

Comment: It appears that [Firefox is experimenting with implementing a native masonry approach that would allow this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/)-- might be worth a read.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will check that!